# Print out the first occurrence of a word in a file beginning with each letter in the Alphabet

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep

I have a file with a list of adjectives A - Z

**How can I print the first word beginning with A, then the first word beginning with B ... all the way to Z?**
I thought grep might be the way. But open to others, awk, python...other.

**Some sample outputs:**

```
$ cat adjectives.txt | head
Adamant: unyielding; a very hard substance
Adroit: clever, resourceful
Amatory: sexual
Animistic: quality of recurrence or reversion to earlier form
Antic: clownish, frolicsome
Arcadian: serene
Baleful: deadly, foreboding
Bellicose: quarrelsome (its synonym belligerent can also be a noun)
Bilious: unpleasant, peevish
Boorish: crude, insensitive

$ cat adjectives.txt | grep '^[ABCDE]' | head
Adamant: unyielding; a very hard substance
Adroit: clever, resourceful
Amatory: sexual
Animistic: quality of recurrence or reversion to earlier form
Antic: clownish, frolicsome
Arcadian: serene
Baleful: deadly, foreboding
Bellicose: quarrelsome (its synonym belligerent can also be a noun)
Bilious: unpleasant, peevish
Boorish: crude, insensitive
```

**So my sample output would be:**

```
Adamant: unyielding; a very hard substance
Baleful: deadly, foreboding
...
Irksome: annoying
Jejune: dull, puerile
...
Wheedling: flattering
Zealous: eager, devoted
```

**File in full from [here](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/100-exquisite-adjectives/)**

```
$ cat adjectives.txt
Adamant: unyielding; a very hard substance
Adroit: clever, resourceful
Amatory: sexual
Animistic: quality of recurrence or reversion to earlier form
Antic: clownish, frolicsome
Arcadian: serene
Baleful: deadly, foreboding
Bellicose: quarrelsome (its synonym belligerent can also be a noun)
Bilious: unpleasant, peevish
Boorish: crude, insensitive
Calamitous: disastrous
Caustic: corrosive, sarcastic; a corrosive substance
Cerulean: sky blue
Comely: attractive
Concomitant: accompanying
Contumacious: rebellious
Corpulent: obese
Crapulous: immoderate in appetite
Defamatory: maliciously misrepresenting
Didactic: conveying information or moral instruction
Dilatory: causing delay, tardy
Dowdy: shabby, old-fashioned; an unkempt woman
Efficacious: producing a desired effect
Effulgent: brilliantly radiant
Egregious: conspicuous, flagrant
Endemic: prevalent, native, peculiar to an area
Equanimous: even, balanced
Execrable: wretched, detestable
Fastidious: meticulous, overly delicate
Feckless: weak, irresponsible
Fecund: prolific, inventive
Friable: brittle
Fulsome: abundant, overdone, effusive
Garrulous: wordy, talkative
Guileless: naive
Gustatory: having to do with taste or eating
Heuristic: learning through trial-and-error or problem solving
Histrionic: affected, theatrical
Hubristic: proud, excessively self-confident
Incendiary: inflammatory, spontaneously combustible, hot
Insidious: subtle, seductive, treacherous
Insolent: impudent, contemptuous
Intransigent: uncompromising
Inveterate: habitual, persistent
Invidious: resentful, envious, obnoxious
Irksome: annoying
Jejune: dull, puerile
Jocular: jesting, playful
Judicious: discreet
Lachrymose: tearful
Limpid: simple, transparent, serene
Loquacious: talkative
Luminous: clear, shining
Mannered: artificial, stilted
Mendacious: deceptive
Meretricious: whorish, superficially appealing, pretentious
Minatory: menacing
Mordant: biting, incisive, pungent
Munificent: lavish, generous
Nefarious: wicked
Noxious: harmful, corrupting
Obtuse: blunt, stupid
Parsimonious: frugal, restrained
Pendulous: suspended, indecisive
Pernicious: injurious, deadly
Pervasive: widespread
Petulant: rude, ill humored
Platitudinous: resembling or full of dull or banal comments
Precipitate: steep, speedy
Propitious: auspicious, advantageous, benevolent
Puckish: impish
Querulous: cranky, whining
Quiescent: inactive, untroublesome
Rebarbative: irritating, repellent
Recalcitrant: resistant, obstinate
Redolent: aromatic, evocative
Rhadamanthine: harshly strict
Risible: laughable
Ruminative: contemplative
Sagacious: wise, discerning
Salubrious: healthful
Sartorial: relating to attire, especially tailored fashions
Sclerotic: hardening
Serpentine: snake-like, winding, tempting or wily
Spasmodic: having to do with or resembling a spasm, excitable,
intermittent
Strident: harsh, discordant; obtrusively loud
Taciturn: closemouthed, reticent
Tenacious: persistent, cohesive,
Tremulous: nervous, trembling, timid, sensitive
Trenchant: sharp, penetrating, distinct
Turbulent: restless, tempestuous
Turgid: swollen, pompous
Ubiquitous: pervasive, widespread
Uxorious: inordinately affectionate or compliant with a wife
Verdant: green, unripe
Voluble: glib, given to speaking
Voracious: ravenous, insatiable
Wheedling: flattering
Withering: devastating
Zealous: eager, devoted
```

Comment: You can use `cat adjectives.txt | grep '^A' | head -1` to get the first row for A, then do the same for B and so on. Put it together with a `for i in A B C ...; do cat adjectives.txt | grep '^$i' | head -1; done` and there you go.

Comment: I don't know why everyone is using `cat` to feed to `grep` when `grep` can open files on its own...

Comment: `grep` will read the start of the file every time. Not very efficient when you reach letter `Z`.

Answer (score 9):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!a[tolower(substr($0,1,1))]++' file
```

this creates a counter for each initial character and only prints when the count is zero (that is the first instance). `tolower()` is there to make it case insensitive, if not needed you can remove. `substr($0,1,1)` extracts the first char from the line.  There is an implicit loop that will repeat this for all lines of the input file.

By changing the script slightly

```
$ awk '++a[substr($0,1,1)]==2' file
```

you can get the second record (if exists) or with `<3` instead of `==2` first 2 records.

if your file is already sorted and cases are consistent, you may opt to a simpler script

```
$ uniq -w1 file
```

The `uniq` command extract the first instance of the compared values, here restricted to first character only.  So, it will extract the first of all letters at once. Add `-i` ignore case flag if cases are not consistent.

Scanning the file once is enough, multiple scans are not necessary...

Comment: tks brief explanation and how do I do it for the 2nd or 3rd....etc word beginning with A ... all the way to Z?

Comment: both will extract all the letters at once.  Please try while I add explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Python version:

```
import itertools

with open('adjectives.txt') as fp:
    # Group lines by first letter. If the lines weren't already sorted, 
    # you could replace fp with sorted(fp).
    groups = itertools.groupby(fp, key=lambda line: line[0])

    for first_letter, group in groups:
        print(next(group), end='')
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `sorted`, the list is already sorted. Using sort + groupby is a clear indicator that something else should be done

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited my answer to reflect the reasonable assumption that the input file is already sorted (the OP's example file is, but I wanted to make sure the code would work in any case).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, with bash :

```
for i in {A..Z}; do grep -m1 ^$i adjectives.txt; done
```

Comment: `grep [$i].` doesn't look for the letter at the start of the word, but anywhere. well, maybe it can work if rest of the text is lowercase.

Comment: True. Should write ^[$i].

Comment: `^$i` should be enough.

Comment: also instead of `| head` you can use `grep -m1` which returns immediately after first match without searching the rest of the file.

Comment: @thanasisp I didn't know about this option. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("adjectives.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# get rid of trailing \n
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines] 

# stable sort
lines.sort(key = lambda s: s[0])

d = {}
for line in lines:
  key = line[0]
  # only the first occurence
  if not key in d:
    d[key] = line

for key in sorted(d.keys()):
  print(d[key])
```